# Using isRequestedSessionIdValid with mock

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I'm trying to test a spring MVC application and I don't know how to mock the request so isRequestedSessionIdValid returns true.

This is my test:

```
@Test
public void testLogin() throws Exception {
    final String url = "/secure/logged.do";
    getMockMvc().perform(get(url).with(user("admin123").password("admin123").roles("0")))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/secure/home.do"))
    .andDo(print());
}
```

The issue is that my session HandlerInterceptorAdapter is redirecting to my no session page:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
    try {
        if (!request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + LOGIN_URL);
            return false;
        }

        // more code
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        // more code
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I'm sure it has to be very easy, but I don't find the solution.

Comment: Is it possible that you use mockito? It is so easy for this operations. If you want use mockito I can answer your question.

Comment: Yes it is possible, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your preHandle(req, resp, handler) method is pure java method. You can test it directly.

```
HttpServletRequest mockRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
HttpServletResponse mockResponse = Mockito.mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
Object handle = Mockito.mock(Object.class);

//most important thing is here
Mockito.when(mockRequest.isRequestedSessionIdValid()).thenReturn(true);
boolean result = new YourClass().preHandle(mockRequest, mockResponse, handle);
Assert.assertEquals(true, result);
```

I hope this solves your question.

Comment: Thanks! it worked and like this is exactly what I was asking for I will check it as accepted. However, I found a better solution for my test, which is adding a `MockHttpSession`: `perform(get(url).session(new MockHttpSession())...` and now `request.isRequestedSessionIdValid()` always returns true.